# JAVA Foreach to Stream

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to convert foreach to streams

```
for (Entity entity : listOfEntitys.getAll()) {
        if (!isEntityDateValid(entity.getStartDate())
                || !isEntityDateValid(entity.getEndDate())) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So i convert it like this

```
  if (listOfEntitys.getAll() != null) {
       return listOfEntitys.getAll().stream().anyMatch(entity-> !isEntityDateValid(entity.getStartDate())
                || !isEntityDateValid(entity.getEndDate()));
    }
```

But i messed it up because it always evaluates the boolean value and i only want to return it when it satisfies the condition

Comment: Conditional return statement cannot be change to pure stream, but if you show us more code probably we can help you

Comment: The null check isn't needed, since the for-each would also fail if `getAll` returned null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the return to happen under certain conditions, your stream command will need to be part of an `if` statement.

```
if (listOfEntities.getAll()!=null && listOfEntities.getAll().stream().anyMatch(...)) {
    return false;
}
```

But it might be clearer using `!allMatch(X && Y)` rather than `anyMatch(!X || !Y)`.

```
if (listOfEntities.getAll()!=null
    && !listOfEntities.getAll().stream()
           .allMatch(entity -> isEntityDateValid(entity.getStartDate())
                     && isEntityDateValid(entity.getEndDate()))) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that `anyMatch` will return `true` if any of the entries matched your condition:

```
return listOfEntitys.getAll().stream().anyMatch(entity-> !isEntityDateValid(entity.getStartDate())
            || !isEntityDateValid(entity.getEndDate()));
```

So add a not in there:

```
return !listOfEntitys.getAll().stream().anyMatch(entity-> !isEntityDateValid(entity.getStartDate())
            || !isEntityDateValid(entity.getEndDate()));
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have a `for` loop that will **return true if all dates are valid, or return false as soon as one is not**.
The `return true` is missing but I guess it's there, else your initial translations wouldn't make sense.

**The proper way to implement this is using `allMatch()`**, which is the method that most accurately conveys the meaning of the loop:

```
return listOfEntitys.getAll().stream()
        .allMatch(e -> isEntityDateValid(e.getStartDate) || isEntityDateValid(e.getEndDate()));
```

This will return true if and only if all entities have valid dates. As soon as one is not valid, it returns false. Just like your `for` loop.

This also has the added benefit that it **avoids negative conditionals**, which is one of the rules to have a cleaner code.